# Associate ASP.NET ApplicationUser In Another Database

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web app. I have connected to a database on localDB ("MyWebAppDatabase"), which already contains many tables. I am accessing this using ADO.NET Entity Framework, and this is all working great.

However, I would like to add a table which references users who use the website: I have a "Subscription" table and would like to associate it with an ApplicationUser. The problem is that the tables containing user information are stored in a separate database (which was automatically generated by the Visual Studio when I created the project under the `DefaultConnection` context), and I don't know how I can perform this association.

What is the best way to go about this? I thought the ideal solution would be if I could move the tables that ASP.NET automatically created for application users into MyWebAppDatabase - then I can easily update the database with the correct tables and foreign keys. Is this correct? If so, how would I go about doing this? I'm not entirely sure where the database is for the application users (I couldn't decipher it from looking at Web.Config and reading the DefaultConnection connection string) and I don't really understand how I would be able to migrate the tables.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally if you can move the tables into a single database you will get the best performance, otherwise you will have to do all of the JOIN's in memory in the application. You can't make foreign key references across database unfortunately.

If you point the connection string for the ASP.NET Identity to the same database that your Subscription table is located in and run the application and create some users it should create those tables automatically.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, thanks what I suspected, but how do I get the database to point to my database? After doing what you suggested previously, I got this message: The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context. Edit: I also just looked in the database tables and no new tables were created.

Comment: Argh it does work, but I just had to change one small thing... I had left `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"` in the connection string tag, but I needed to change it to `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` ! But thanks for your help, you got me pointed in the right direction!